# How to make a UITableViewController transparent on the top?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

In my iPhone application I have presented controller:

```
 ShareResourceItemViewController* controller = [[ShareResourceItemViewController alloc] initWithSharedResourceItem:[selectedItems objectAtIndex:0]];    
    [self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Then in this controller I want to make it transparent on the top. I tried:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self performSelector:@selector(test) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];

}

-(void)test{
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.opaque = NO;
    self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
}
```

The background was cleaned but controller is not transparent and I can not see previous controller? How can I fix this?

Comment: give background color clear color for that viewcontroller view.

Comment: try this:     `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];`

Answer (score 1):

Make the tableview cells background color also to clear color.

Comment: Remember you should change the colour of a cell in willDisplayCellAtIndexPath

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you want to see your previous View Controller, you want to not present a new view controller, but rather, put a new `UIView` on top of your View Controller. View Controllers can't be transparent or not, but views can. Give it a try:

```
ShareResourceItemViewController* controller = [[ShareResourceItemViewController alloc] initWithSharedResourceItem:[selectedItems objectAtIndex:0]];
[self.view addSubview:controller.view];
```